# Change currency symbol automatically based on current location

Tags: android

I'm using the following code to retrieve the user's local currency symbol:

```
     public static String getCurrencySymbol() {
        Currency currency = Currency.getInstance(Locale.getDefault());
        return currency.getSymbol();
}
```

However, one of my users moved from UK to the US and his currency symbol is still showing as the British Pound. Is there some way to make it show as a US Dollar symbol ($) now that's he's moved to the US?

Answer (score 1):

I think `Locale.getDefault()` is just related to the language settings on the phone and has nothing to do with the current location (of the phone). That's why the actual Locale did not change, even though your User moved to the US.

A possible solution would be to add a settings option in your App, so the user can change his currency when needed. This option then would just change your application wide Locale used for the currency.